# Hibernate batch update issue

Tags: java, hibernate, mariadb, sql-update, insert-update

For a simple batch update of a MariaDB table, properly mapped as a Hibernate entity class, a simple update via Hibernate produces the error

```
org.hibernate.StaleStateException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update
```

Each table record is modeled by an `Entity` class, which is a simple POJO that needs to be updated (if it already exists) or inserted as a new object (if it does not exist in the table), with a primary `id` field (not auto-incremented) and some other values, all scalar. The error can be reproduced by the following method.

```
public static void update(Set<Long> ids) {
  Session session = createSession();
  Transaction t = session.beginTransaction();
  try {
    for (Long id : ids) {
      Entity entity = session.get(Entity.class, id);
      if (entity == null) {
        entity = new Entity();
      }
      entity.setId(id);
      // Other entity value settings
      session.saveOrUpdate(entity);
    }
    transaction.commit();
  } catch (Exception e) {
    transaction.rollback();
  } finally {
    session.close();
  }
}
```

What is the correct way of implementing the above operation in Hibernate?

Answer (score 0):

You are using [saveOrUpdate()](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch11.html#objectstate-saveorupdate) in this way Hibernate decides by his own logic what is a new (Transient) and what is an old (Persisted) object and depends on this performs `save()` or `update()` method accordingly.

**Hibernate assumes that an instance is an unsaved transient instance if:**

- The identifier property is `null`.
- The version or timestamp property (if it exists) is `null`.
- A new instance of the same persistent class, created by Hibernate internally, has the same database identifier values as the given instance.
- You supply an `unsaved-value` in the mapping document for the class, and the value of the identifier property matches. The `unsaved-value` attribute is also available for version and timestamp mapping elements.
- Entity data with the same identifier value isn't in the second-level cache.
- You supply an implementation or `org.hibernate.Interceptor` and return `Boolean.TRUE` from `Interceptor.isUnsaved()` after checking the instance in your code.

**Otherwise:** entity will be determined like already saved persisted

In your example, Hibernate did not determine the new (Transient) object and as result, perform `update()` method for it. It produced `UPDATE` instead of `INSERT` statement. `UPDATE` statement for not existing record returns zero updated records, so it is the reason for your exception.

**Solution:** explicitly use [save()](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch11.html#objectstate-makingpersistent) method for new entities:

```java
    public void update(Set<Long> ids) {
        Session session = getSessionFactory().openSession();
        Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
        try {
            for (Long id : ids) {
                HibernateEntity entity = session.get(HibernateEntity.class, id);
                if (entity == null) {
                    entity = new HibernateEntity();
                }
                // Other entity value settings
                entity.setValue(entity.getValue() + "modification");

                if (entity.getId() == null) {
                    entity.setId(id);
                    session.save(entity);
                }
            }
            transaction.commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            transaction.rollback();
        } finally {
            session.close();
        }
    }
```

`update()` method is not required to call explicitly. Transactional persistent instances (i.e. objects loaded, saved, created or queried by the Session) can be manipulated by the application, and any changes to persistent state will be persisted when the Session is `flushed`. According to [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch11.html#objectstate-modifying).